# MYSQL field ID value changing

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

Databases:

listings

```
|  ID  |  TITLE  |  COMPANY_ID  |
|  1   |   One   |      1       |
|  2   |   One   |      1       |
|  3   |   One   |      1       |
```

Companies

```
|  ID  |  NAME  |
|  1   |   One  |
|  2   |   Two  |
|  3   |  Three |
```

I have the PDO MYSQL statement:

```
"SELECT 
listings.ID,
listings.TITLE,
listings.COMPANY_ID,
companies.ID,
companies.NAME 
FROM listings INNER JOIN companies ON (listings.COMPANY_ID = companies.ID ) WHERE (listings.TITLE = :p1 AND companies.NAME = :p2 )LIMIT 10"
```

The associative array output:

```
Array
(
    [ID] => 1
    [TITLE] => analyst
    [COMPANY_ID] => 1
    [NAME] => one
)
Array
(
    [ID] => 1
    [TITLE] => analyst
    [COMPANY_ID] => 1
    [NAME] => one
)
Array
(
    [ID] => 1
    [TITLE] => analyst
    [COMPANY_ID] => 1
    [NAME] => one
)
```

When executing this query, my ID field that is being outputted to the PHP fetch associative array is being returned as 1.

With the exception to the ID, the output works as expected.

Why is my ID value changing?

```
______________________
```

METHOD:

```
protected function search_joined($parameters, $func){
        $field = "*";
        if(isset($parameters["fields"])){
            if($parameters["fields"] != "*" && gettype($parameters["fields"]) == gettype(array())){
                if(count($parameters["fields"]) == 2){
                    $field = "";
                    foreach($parameters["fields"] as $key=>$v){
                        foreach($v as $v_){
                            $field.= $parameters["tables"][$key] . "." . $v_ . ",";
                        }
                    }
                    $field = rtrim($field, ",");
                }
            }
        }

        $cond_ = "";
        $values = array();      
        if(gettype($parameters["condArry"]) == gettype(array())){
            $COND_TYPE = " AND ";
            foreach($parameters["condArry"] as $v){
                $operator = " = ";
                if($v[1][0] == "%" || substr($v[1], -1) == "%"){
                    $operator=" LIKE ";
                }
                if(substr($v[1], 5) == "L::_>"){
                    $operator=" > ";
                    $v[1] = str_replace($v[1], "L::_>", "");
                }
                if($v[1][0] == "!"){
                    $operator=" != ";
                    //$v[1] = str_replace($v[1], "!", "");
                    $v[1] = substr($v[1], 1);
                }
                $COND_TYPE = (
                    (isset($v[2]))? 
                        (
                            ($v[2] == "&")? " AND " : 
                                (
                                    (($v[2]=="||")? " OR ": "")
                                )
                        ): " AND "
                );
                $unique = md5($v[0] . $v[1]);

                $cond_.= $v[0] . $operator . ":".substr($v[0], strpos($v[0], ".") + 1).$unique. " " . $COND_TYPE . " ";
                $values[':'.substr($v[0], strpos($v[0], ".") + 1).$unique] = $v[1];
            }
            $cond_ = "WHERE (" . substr($cond_, 0, strlen($COND_TYPE)*(-1)) . ")";
        }

        //$cond_ = rtrim($cond_, ",");
        $joiner = $parameters["tables"][0] . "." . $parameters["joiner"][0] . "=" . $parameters["tables"][1] . "." . $parameters["joiner"][1] . " ";

        $sql = "SELECT ". $field . " FROM " . $parameters["tables"][0] . " INNER JOIN " . $parameters["tables"][1] . " ON (" . $joiner . ") " .$cond_ . (isset($parameters["LIMIT"])? "LIMIT " . $parameters["LIMIT"]: "");
        echo $sql;
        if(isset($parameters["test"])){
            if($parameters["test"] == true){
                echo "<br>". $sql . "<br>";
            }
        }
        //echo "<br>". $sql . "<br>";
        $q = $parameters["connection"]->prepare($sql);

        foreach($values as $key => $v){
            $q->bindvalue($key, $v);
            echo "<br>" . $key . " : " . $v . "<br>";
        }
        $q->execute();
        while($row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            if(!$func($row)){
                break;
            }
        }
        $conTableArry = null;
    }
```

CALLER:

```
$params_= array(
            "connection"=>$this->connection_,
            "tables"=>array("listings", "companies"),
            "joiner"=>array("COMPANY_ID","ID"),
            "fields"=> array(
                array(
                    "ID",
                    "TITLE",
                    "PAYMIN", 
                    "PAYMAX", 
                    "GEO_LOCATIONS_ID", 
                    "CRIMINAL_HISTORY_REQ", 
                    "EVAL_EXAM_REQ", 
                    "AGE_REQ", 
                    "EX_REQ", 
                    "DRIVERS_LICENSE_REQ", 
                    "CERTIFICATE_REQ", 
                    "EDUCATION_REQ", 
                    "RESUME_REQ" , 
                    "POSITIONS",
                    "COMPANY_ID"
                ),
                array(
                    "ID",
                    "NAME"
                )
            ),
            "condArry"=>array(array("listings.TITLE", "analyst"), array("companies.NAME", "suitespec")),
            "LIMIT"=>$LIMIT,
        );

        parent::search_joined($params_, function($r){
            out($r);
            return true;
        });
```

Comment: show your actual pdo code. we can't help you with that.

Comment: Need to show your php code.

Comment: Alright, but dont complain if you dont understand something because of missing resources. ill update the posting now with a snippet.

Comment: I am certain the issue is the mysql statement and not PHP. I never make a call to change the ID or the associative value of the ID.

Comment: The problem is that you're using `ID` for two columns. PHP is choosing to use `companies.ID` (which is always 1 because of your join condition).  If you do `companies.ID AS CID` instead, you'll have 5 elements in your array instead of 4 (with the new one being CID).

Comment: @patrick thank you, i knew the solution was simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to solve this by using unique column names for your result set (you currently use `ID` twice).

Change your SQL to something like this:

```
"SELECT 
    listings.ID,
    listings.TITLE,
    listings.COMPANY_ID,
    companies.ID AS CID,
    companies.NAME 
FROM listings
    INNER JOIN companies ON (listings.COMPANY_ID = companies.ID )
WHERE (listings.TITLE = :p1
    AND companies.NAME = :p2 )LIMIT 10"
```

Notice the 5th line of that.  I've changed it from `companies.ID` to `companies.ID AS CID`.

Comment: Yeah using AS LID on my ID solved the problem. At the moment i am extending it from the parameters (the caller). I will need to write  another method to detect this situation. Thank YOU!

Answer (score 3):

You've got some confusing syntax in your SQL

```
SELECT 
     listings.ID,
     listings.TITLE,
     listings.COMPANY_ID,
     companies.ID,
     companies.NAME 
FROM listings 
     INNER JOIN companies ON (listings.COMPANY_ID = companies.ID ) 
WHERE (listings.TITLE = :p1 AND companies.NAME = :p2 )
LIMIT 10
```

You have two `ID` columns and no aliasing. So you're likely getting the second `ID` back. Try aliasing the second `ID` column and trying again

```
SELECT 
     listings.ID,
     listings.TITLE,
     listings.COMPANY_ID,
     companies.ID AS comp_id,
     companies.NAME
```

Comment: Your answer was correct as well, but patrick beat you to the punch line!